# Vogella Android Tutorial, Compiler error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development and following the Vogella Introduction to Android development with Android Studio - Tutorial located here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html#androidstudio_starter

I started having a problem at step 19.4 and on. I have exact same code as shown in tutorial but Android Studio shows an error in MainActivity.java stating it cannot resolve symbol 'Constants' and build fails with compiler error. I would like to know what I am missing since every step has been followed and all code matches that listed in the tutorial.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.deluxaur.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "onCreated called");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onCLick(View view) {
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input);
    String string = input.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/main_input"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_input"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_input"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just saying that Constants class is not recognized. There are many ways you can fix this.

1. You may create Constants class with static LOG string variable in it

   ```
   public class Constants {
       public static final String LOG = "MyLogTag";
   }
   ```
2. The following code is optional and not needed for the functionality of your program. It is there to help provide some extra logs in order for you to have a better understanding of what is happening in your application but is not necessary.

   ```
   //These three lines are optional
   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(Constants.LOG, "onCreated called");
   }
   ```
3. Or you can simply change the String key. The `Log.d()` method takes two `String`s the first is used for the tag and the second is the message. If you just provide another valid `String` it will work fine.

   ```
   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Log.d("A KEY", "onCreated called");
   }
   ```

Comment: All 3 of these options fix the problem with compiling and running the app but I am just now noticing that Android Studio is showing warnings in MainActivity.java stating that the method `onClick(android.view.view)` is never used and the variable `string` in the line `String string = input.getText().toString();` is never used. On running the app, the layout is displayed and the text field takes input but it crashes when hitting the button. Again am I missing something or is the tutorial out of date?

Comment: Your question is already out of that scope, and the answer does not affect any of the other functionalities.. The answer already simply answered the question.. you may create a new post for that problem.. ^__^.

Comment: but to hint you out.. it warns you because it truly wasnt called.. it was just a warning.. it wont affect runtime mostly.. you may want to use that method somewhere